# Developing iOS DMC app based on UPnPx library on Google code

Tags: ios, upnp, dlna

I am developing an iOS app that would be used as a DLNA technology based DMC (Digital Media Controller) for devices capable of the UPnP protocol. I am using the UPnPx iOS library available on code.google.com and have successfully built and run the demo application. I am able to browse the content of the DMS (Digital media server) hosted on my Macbook Pro. I am using serviio DMS application for this.

Now my problem is that when I run the app on the iOS device, I am able to browse all the content shared by my DMS, but in the `UITableView` footer section I am just getting the text "No Renderer selected". That means the app is not able to find the DMR (Digital Media renderer) in the same Wi-Fi network OR I don't have the DMR on my network.

Can you please suggest to me any DMR app on either iOS device OR on Mac OS X that this library can identify? I have Android devices as well so if any free DMR Android app is available for Android then please suggest me so that I can test and develop the app further.

I just observed the XBMC app for Mac and XBMC remote control app for iOS devices. I want to develop a similar app. Does this require me to write my own DMR app so that my app can control it from within OR based on UPnP technology, my app can control any DMR in the same Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad for this site. Please try to focus it on one thing and add some more detail. For example, add links to the library on code.google.com and the various other apps/libraries that you mentioned. Also, add some of the code where you are seeing the issues.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/upnpx/ is the link

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients

On iOS/MacOS not much. No idea why. There is good selection for Android. I personally can confirm BubbleUPnP and UPnPlay working. You definitely don't need to write your own DMR, unless you want to. It can be as easy as compiling ready made [Cling DMR on Android](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/mediarenderer/).

Comment: Thanks Pavel,
I could test succesfully using the Bubble UPnP Android app and could easily play the Audio files exposed by my DMS on Macbook Pro.I can select the song in my iOS demo app and the same is played on the Android device which acts as DMR.Now the only thing i need to work out is to control the volume of the Android app playing the audio file from within my iOS demo app acting as DMC.Hope you may help me Or guide me in this case . Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your iOS demo app is capable of initiating a DMR playback, then you already know how to execute remote service functions. You needed at least `SetAVTransportURI` and `Play` on `AVTransport` service. Controlling DMR volume is as simple as executing `SetVolume` function on DMR service `RenderingControl`. For further informations, see the [relevant UPnP doc](http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-RenderingControl-v1-Service.pdf).